# Migrate from Eclipse to Android studio: only empty build.gradle exported

Tags: eclipse, android-studio

The project works well in Eclipse and I have upgraded the android SDK to 22.0.1 too. when I follow the  [instruction](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)
1, In Eclipse, select File > Export.
2, In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.
3, Select the project you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

But the problem is the exported build.gradle is empty.only one comments there:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
```

and this empty file is never able to guide the android studio to import the project successfully.

Does anyone has idea what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: That empty build.gradle usually comes inside a folder which contains multiple projects (a project and multiple android libraries). When you use export to gradle feature in Eclipse it generates a build.gradle that does not proper reflects you project dependencies and you have to make some changes. Did you look in deep folder if there is other build.gradle? because this never happen to me.

Comment: You are right. there is another build.gradle file inside the "google-play-services_lib" sub folder ( the project uses google play server) and it's not empty. But when I try to import this new build.gradle from the android studio, it's still not successful. it's still stuck at "building google play service lib" gradle project info. Do you know if there is any way to manually modify the  two build file to work round this issue? Thanks

Comment: yes, you can modify as you want, you can check in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide
post the output log when you try to import to gradle.

Comment: Looks it's not simple. I copied the content from the build.gradle of "google-play-services_lib" sub folder to the root folder , and import it from the android studio , it's stuck at " building xxxx " gradle project info.